# Android NDK/Camera2 Create OpenGL Surface from `ImageReader` Surface / Frame Processing

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-camera2

I'm trying to create an app that streams Frames from the Camera, draws a red box onto the Frame using Skia, and finally displays it on the screen (preview).

I've managed to set up Camera2 and hooked it up to a `SurfaceView` which shows the Camera preview, but I am not sure how to properly set up the in-between frame processing part.

I tried to create an `ImageReader` (Java):

```java
// create image reader
imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 3)
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
  val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
  Log.d(TAG, "Frame: ${image.width} x ${image.height}")
  nativeOnDraw(image)
  image.close()
}, null)
```

Create an OpenGL/Skia surface from that (C++):

```cpp
EGLDisplay eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
if (eglDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get EGL Display! " + std::to_string(glGetError()));
}

EGLint major, minor;
if (!eglInitialize(eglDisplay, &major, &minor)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize EGL! " + std::to_string(glGetError()));
}

EGLint att[] = {EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
                EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
                EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
                EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                EGL_NONE};

EGLint numConfigs;
EGLConfig eglConfig;
if (!eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, att, &eglConfig, 1, &numConfigs) ||
    numConfigs == 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to choose a GL Config! " + std::to_string(glGetError()));
}

EGLint contextAttribs[] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE};
EGLContext eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay,
                                         eglConfig,
                                         EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                                         contextAttribs);
if (eglContext == EGL_NO_CONTEXT) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create a GL Context! " + std::to_string(glGetError()));
}

EGLSurface eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, nativeWindow, nullptr);
if (!eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set current surface! " + std::to_string(glGetError()));
}

GLint buffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &buffer);
GLint stencil;
glGetIntegerv(GL_STENCIL_BITS, &stencil);
GLint samples;
glGetIntegerv(GL_SAMPLES, &samples);

// Create the Skia backend context
auto backendInterface = GrGLMakeNativeInterface();
auto grContext = GrDirectContext::MakeGL(backendInterface);
if (grContext == nullptr) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Skia Context from GL Context! " + std::to_string(glGetError()));
}

auto maxSamples = grContext->maxSurfaceSampleCountForColorType(kRGBA_8888_SkColorType);
if (samples > maxSamples)
    samples = maxSamples;

GrGLFramebufferInfo fbInfo;
fbInfo.fFBOID = buffer;
fbInfo.fFormat = 0x8058; // GR_GL_RGBA8

auto renderTarget = GrBackendRenderTarget(width, height, samples, stencil, fbInfo);

struct RenderContext {
    EGLDisplay display;
    EGLSurface surface;
};
auto ctx = new RenderContext({eglDisplay, eglSurface});

auto surface = SkSurface::MakeFromBackendRenderTarget(
        grContext.get(), renderTarget, kBottomLeft_GrSurfaceOrigin,
        kRGBA_8888_SkColorType, nullptr, nullptr,
        [](void *addr) {
            auto ctx = reinterpret_cast<RenderContext *>(addr);
            eglDestroySurface(ctx->display, ctx->surface);
            delete ctx;
        },
        reinterpret_cast<void *>(ctx));

// `surface` can now be used for drawing
```

..and finally passed it to the Camera (Java):

```java
val captureRequestBuilder = captureSession.device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.surface)
val captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build()
captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, null, cameraHandler)
```

But this just crashes with the following error(s):

```
D  eglCreateContext: 0xb40000735bdf0790: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D  eglMakeCurrent: 0xb40000735bdf0790: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x75819f0100) (first time)
I  Re-rendering camera page with active camera. Device: "back (0)" (1280x720 @ 30fps)
D  onSurfaceCreated()
D  onSurfaceChanged()
D  Camera 0 successfully opened
E  [ImageReader-640x480f23m3-1403-0](id:57b00000002,api:1,p:1403,c:1403) connect: already connected (cur=1 req=4)
W  Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:648: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
E  Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
```

What struck out to me is the `ImageReader ... already connected` error - is it not possible to create an OpenGL/Skia surface from the existing `ImageReader` surface?

Is there another approach to do this that doesn't require expensive CPU buffer copies of the Image each frame?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you're trying to do here, but are you using the `Surface` from `ImageReader.getSurface` to create the `eglSurface`? That's fine, but that means you're setting up a rendering path of `GPU -> ImageReader`.

You then try to connect the camera to the ImageReader (`Camera -> ImageReader`), which errors out since you're already feeding the ImageReader from the GPU.

If you want `Camera -> GPU`, use a [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture) to turn camera frames into GL textures (create a `Surface` from it via a constructor).

But perhaps you need to clarify what the pipeline you're trying to create is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I think `Camera -> GPU` is what I want - I want to draw stuff onto the Camera Frame before rendering it in a Preview. The reason why I wanted to use `ImageReader` is because it allows me to run code on every Camera Frame. How would I achieve that with `SurfaceTexture`?

Comment: SurfaceTexture has https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener which will be called for every new frame, as long as you can keep up with the frame rate.

Comment: Hey! Sorry been a few weeks. I picked this up again - so I got my Camera to draw into the OpenGL texture - how would I then draw this into one or more Surfaces, e.g. MediaRecorder and ImageReader? Do I need to use an intermediate Frame Buffer Object?Then create OpenGL contexts for each of those surfaces (one for MediaRecorder, one for ImageReader)?